# express-session and passport Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-session

I'm getting an error in Node.js when I try to login or signup.
I'm using connect-mongodb-session, but when I setup an store, it happen.

```
serializing user:
{ _id: 57cf316758531915c8a93dd7,
  email: 'a',
  password: '$2a$10$1.qkrnLWLiG6zFXHTII1pOsHs0sWdFrmfgaGO.6ZY4q/TwZ7E0RTG',
  username: 'a',
  followers: [],
   following: [],
  likes: [],
  orders: [],
   __v: 0 }
POST /login 302 793.072 ms - 46
_http_outgoing.js:344
  throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
^
 at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Fabian Gutierrez\Documents\GitHub\maravillarte\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:718:10)
at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Fabian Gutierrez\Documents\GitHub\maravillarte\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:163:12)
at done (C:\Users\Fabian Gutierrez\Documents\GitHub\maravillarte\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:957:10)
 at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\Fabian Gutierrez\Documents\GitHub\maravillarte\node_modules\express-handlebars\lib\utils.js:26:13)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)

 Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

I tried a lot of thing, but I don't understand what happens

this is my code, app.s:

```
  var passport = require('passport');
  var expressSession = require('express-session');
  var MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(expressSession);//session for stores sessions
  //MONTAR EL STORE DE SESSIONS
  var mystore = new MongoDBStore(dbConfig.store,function(error) {
    if (error){
      console.log(error)    
    }
  });

  app.use(expressSession({
    cookie:{ maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 },
    httpOnly: true,
    store: mystore,
    secret: 'mifuckingkey',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    unset: 'destroy'
  }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  // Using the flash middleware provided by connect-flash to store messages in session
  // and displaying in templates
  var flash = require('connect-flash');
  app.use(flash());

  // Inicializar Passport
  var initPassport = require('./lib/passport/init');
  initPassport(passport);

  var routes = require('./routes/index')(passport);
  app.use('/', routes);
```

init.js

```
     var login = require('./login');
            var signup = require('./signup');
            var User = require('../../models/user');

            module.exports = function(passport){

                // Passport needs to be able to serialize and deserialize       users to support persistent login sessions
                passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
                    console.log('serializing user: ');console.log(user);
                    done(null, user._id);
                });

                passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
                    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
                        console.log('deserializing user:',user);
                        done(err, user);
                    });
                });
                console.log("passport iniciado")
                // Setting up Passport Strategies for Login and    SignUp/Registration
                 login(passport);
                signup(passport);
            }
```

signup.js

```
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(passport){

passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
        passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, username, password, done) { 
        // check in mongo if a user with username exists or not
        User.findOne({ 'username' :  username }, 
            function(err, user) {
                // In case of any error, return using the done method
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                // Username does not exist, log the error and redirect back
                if (!user){
                    console.log('User Not Found with username '+username);
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'User Not found.'));                 
                }
                // User exists but wrong password, log the error 
                if (!isValidPassword(user, password)){
                    console.log('Invalid Password');
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Invalid Password')); // redirect back to login page
                }
                // User and password both match, return user from done method
                // which will be treated like success
                return done(null, user);
            }
        );

    })
);


var isValidPassword = function(user, password){
    return bCrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
}

}
```

signup.js

```
 var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
        var User = require('../../models/user');
        var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

        module.exports = function(passport){

            passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
                    passReqToCallback : true
                },
                function(req, username, password, done) { 
                    // check in mongo if a user with username exists or not
                    User.findOne({ 'username' :  username }, 
                        function(err, user) {
                            // In case of any error, return using the done method
                            if (err)
                                return done(err);
                            // Username does not exist, log the error and redirect back
                            if (!user){
                                console.log('User Not Found with username '+username);
                                return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'User Not found.'));                 
                            }
                            // User exists but wrong password, log the error 
                            if (!isValidPassword(user, password)){
                                console.log('Invalid Password');
                                return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Invalid Password')); // redirect back to login page
                            }
                            // User and password both match, return user from done method
                            // which will be treated like success
                            return done(null, user);
                        }
                    );

                })
            );


            var isValidPassword = function(user, password){
                return bCrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
            }

        }
```

and part of router

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
                  res.render('home', { title: 'Maravillarte',user:req.user});
                });

                router.get('/vender', function(req, res, next) {
                  res.render('register', { title: 'Express',layout:'register' });
                });
                /*///////////////////////////////////////
                INICIO DE SESSION
                ///////////////////////////////////////*/
                router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
                    successRedirect: '/',
                    failureRedirect: '/',
                    failureFlash: true,
                }));
                    router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
                  res.render('pages/login', { title: 'Maravillarte',user:req.user});
                });
                /*///////////////////////////////////////
                REGISTRARSE
                ///////////////////////////////////////*/
                router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
                    successRedirect: '/',
                    failureRedirect: '/',
                    failureFlash: true
                }));
```

Comment: Can you show your login and signup function, where you are sending response back?

Comment: I added login.js and router.js, thanks

Answer (score 1):

in your init.js,

```
// Setting up Passport Strategies for Login and    SignUp/Registration
                 login(passport);
                signup(passport);
```

Both routes res.render send the response back to the client asynchronously. So, when second route tries to send the response with res.render response of the first route already been sent. That's why it throws error like can't set header after they are sent.

follow the given [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) below for the example.

Comment: Can you give me and example of how to solve it?, i'm very baffled with that.

thanks

Comment: I did it, but. I'm in the same state as before :(

Comment: When i was stuck with this problem i have used the same tutorial. And if you wish you can find complete source code here.

https://github.com/scotch-io/easy-node-authentication/tree/local

Comment: yeah but, when i have been disabled connect-mongodb-session, it works well, it's when I active the store that the error happens